# Is there way to convert a hibernate or nhibernate query results to a string?

Tags: c#, sql-server, hibernate, nhibernate, ssms

Is there way to convert a hibernate or nhibernate query results to a string ? 
Basically I'm looking to duplicate "sql management studio" functionality which shows list of results regardless of query type.

So for example, if my query is

```
select firstName, lastName from table t
```

is there way to concatenate the result into a string without doing the formatting my self ?

Comment: Do you know what you want the resulting string to look like?  Perhaps `John Smith`, or `{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith"}`, or `John, Smith`, or `"John", "Smith"`, or `Smith, John`, or...

Comment: I think this question is really about object serialization or string formatting, not about Hibernate or NHibernate.

Comment: For your "without mentioning the column names" goal, we're talking about [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29).  You're a bit vague on whether you're working with Hibernate or with NHibernate.  Which are we talking about: Java, or .NET?

Comment: @DanielSchilling, I'm working on .NET with nhibernate. My aim is to execute arbitrary queries from a webpage and then display back the results (or error). This will help me debug our test setup while not having access to SQL Management Studio. So the format doesn't really matter as long as the output is being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(MAX), col) 
FROM table
```

And if you mean you want to concatenate all the column results, just add them together with a string somewhere in the concatenation.

Comment: Is there way to do this without mentioning the column names ? As in regardless of the query, just collate all results into a string ? Also, can you please elaborate on "just add them together with a string somewhere in the concatenation" (Sorry, I'm a noob to SQL and hibernate).